# How do I turn this simple command into something that loops from a list of remote systems?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I received a request to run this on each of my systems which pulls a list of installed applications and outputs it into a text file. I then have to combine all of these things into something more readable which will take a while. I am learning Powershell and want to make this be executed from one system, pull from a list of servers in a text file and run this query from one place against all of the systems:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | Format-Table –AutoSize > "$Env:userprofile\desktop\Installed Programs for $env:computername.txt"
```

I've started working on it but am thinking I am missing something to get this to work. I am currently piping this to a string to then output to a csv (I am open to suggestions). This is what I have so far.

```
# Computer running this script
$WhoAmI = $env:ComputerName

$ServerList = get-content -path "C:\scripts\ServerList.txt"
$Path = "C:\scripts\results"

foreach ($server in $ServerList) 
    {   

        $InstalledApps = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server {Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* }

            $Results += $InstalledApps |
                Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
                    Out-String  


    }
Write-Host $InstallApps

# $InstallApps | export-csv "$Path\InstalledFiles.csv"
```

I currently am testing the functionality of the loop by just trying to get it to write to the screen. I only get a blank response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't getting output because you used the (undefined) variable `$InstallApps` instead of the variable `$results`.

With that said, I wouldn't recommend doing string concatenation in a loop. Something like this would be a more elegant approach:

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\scripts\ServerList.txt' | ForEach-Object {
    $server = $_
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
        Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*
    } | Select-Object @{n='Server';e={$server}}, DisplayName, DisplayVersion,
                      Publisher, InstallDate
} | Export-Csv 'C:\scripts\results\InstalledPrograms.csv' -NoType
```

Comment: This looks interesting and I will give it a try. I realized my mistake above earlier (see my update below) and got it working using txt formatting but it is ugly output (not the fault of the script. It's that way when using the solo command).

Comment: Works like a charm. I very much appreciate this. I am still learning powershell and I have a template of how to do arrays like this and outputting the results into a csv. Very useful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I kind of figured it out. Rested eyes on a fresh day. Some mistakes in what I am writing out, etc.  I am open to improvements if anyone has anything to contribute.

**EDIT:** I got it working mostly with the following but the output is messy.  Open to suggestions.

---

```
# Computer running this script

$ServerList = get-content -path "C:\scripts\ServerList.txt"
$Path = "C:\scripts\results"

foreach ($server in $ServerList) 
    {   

    $Results += "Results for $server"

        $InstalledApps = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* }

            $Results += $InstalledApps |
                Select DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
                    Out-String  


    }

# Write-Host $Results

$Results | out-file -filepath "$Path\InstalledPrograms.txt" -width 200
```